# Should I use poisson distribution to solve this problem here

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

It is expected that a computer will fail after it is on for 8 hours.

(i)Determine the probability that the computer will have at least one failure in a 24 hour day.
(ii) A lab contains 20 such computers. Determine the probability that at least one computer will fail in that lab in one day.

(iii) Determine the probability that between 4 and 16 computers will fail during a particular day.

---

-for the first part of the question , I used poisson distribution formula

8 hours --->  1 time broken
24 hours ---> 3 times broken

let X be the number of times the computer fails
P(at least one ) = P(X>= 1)   = 1-P(X<1)

using mean as 3 for this question
1-P(X<1) = 1 - ( e^-3)(3^0/0!)
= 0.9502

-for the second part , when using approximation to binomial ,
n = 20  p = 0.9502
I am getting the probability = 1  , which seems to be incorrect

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You need yo relate the time to failure of 8 hours to the exponential distribution. This will let you calculate the rate constant $\lambda$ for the questions.

Comment: If the probability that a computer fails at least once in a day is 95%, it wouldn't surprise me that the probability at least one computer of 20 fails a day is even closer to 1.

Comment: For the last question, is it that between 4 and 16 computers each fail exactly once, or at least once, or that there is a total of 4-16 failures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single computer, the expected failures in a day are $\mu=3$.  The Poisson probability that there is at least one failure is $P(k\geq 1; \mu)= 1-P(k=0; \mu) = 1 - e^{-\mu} \approx 0.95$ as you find.

The previous result, for a single computer, is quite large, so if there are $n=20$ computers, we can expect the chance that at least one fails to be even closer to one.  I would write $P(k\geq 1; \mu, n) = 1- P(k=0; \mu, n) = 1-(P(k=0; \mu))^n = 1 - e^{-n \mu} \approx 1$.

Comment: In R: (i) code `p = pexp(1, 3); p` returns $0.9502129;$
 (ii) code `1 - dbinom(0, 20, p)` returns $1;$ (iii) one possible interpretation: code `diff(pbinom(c(3,16), 20, p))` $0.01567554.$ Upvote (+1) for parts (i) & (ii), in case whole page doesn't get obliterated on account of OP's showing no effert.